# Spring Rest Template usage causes EOFException

Tags: android, spring, eof, android-annotations

I'm receiving `java.io.EOFException`'s when using Spring REST template on Android.

The stacktrace cause reads like this:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:49)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:55)
at org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper.getStatusCode(BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper.java:47)
at com.company.util.LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:33)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
at com.company.api.interceptor.AuthTokenInterceptor.intercept(AuthTokenInterceptor.java:51)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:67)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:475)
... 14 more
```

Another similar stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: null; nested exception is java.io.EOFException
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:490)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:438)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:414)
at com.company.api.ApiClient_.logLoginAttempt(ApiClient_.java:299)
at com.company.security.CompanyAuthenticationService$2.onCreateCall(CompanyAuthenticationService.java:206)
at com.company.api.SafeApiCall.doInBackground(SafeApiCall.java:49)
at com.company.api.SafeApiCall.doInBackground(SafeApiCall.java:22)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:49)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:55)
at org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper.getStatusCode(BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper.java:47)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:476)
... 13 more
```

This is all happening on Android 4.1.2, installed on my Xoom tablet.

The problem appears and disappears. It's not triggered by long requests either. The server part is running on a machine within the local network. When I try to run the API Calls through `curl`, it works just fine.

**AuthTokenInterceptor**:

```
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] data, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(mAuthToken)) {
        headers.add((mIsOAuth ? "Authorization" : "authToken"), (mIsOAuth ? "Bearer " : "") + mAuthToken);
    }
    return execution.execute(request, data);
}
```

**LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor**:

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] bytes, ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException {
    Log.d(TAG, "To     : " + httpRequest.getURI());
    Log.d(TAG, "Method : " + httpRequest.getMethod().name());
    Log.d(TAG, "Data   : " + new String(bytes));

    for (Object key : httpRequest.getHeaders().keySet()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Header <" + key + ">: " + httpRequest.getHeaders().get(key));
    }

    final ClientHttpResponse response = clientHttpRequestExecution.execute(httpRequest, bytes);

    if (response != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.getStatusCode());
        if (response.getBody() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + convertStreamToString(response.getBody()));
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

The Rest Template is configured like this:

```
final RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(false);
template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
template.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(template.getRequestFactory()));
ApiUtils.addAuthTokenHeaderToRestTemplate(template, mAuthToken, false);
ApiUtils.addRequestLoggingToRestTemplate(template);
```

The API call in question that crashed here is described in the Android annotations based interface:

```
@Post("/user/memberships")
@Accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
CompanyApiResponse saveGroupMembership(UserGroupMembership membership) throws RestClientException;
```

Things I've tried:

- Removed LoggingInterceptor
- Called all API calls by CURL
- Removed call BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory - **Helped a little but the error still occurs.**
- Tested it on Android 2.3 - **the error cannot be reproduced**

I've been reading various forums posts, the EOF exception seems to appear if URLs are incorrect, which I double checked in this case.

Also of note, once the EOF Exception occurs, the call not even reaches the server side.

Where would be a good point to continue the search for a fix? Is this a Android 4.1 inconvenience?

While debugging this issue, I also found https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ANDROID-102 which prevented me from seeing the real error (EOF) before.

---

**Update:** Just found http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/issues/detail?id=116 -  it might be related.

The fix is also outlined in https://codereview.appspot.com/6225045/ - so it might've been merged for 4.1.

Comment: Note: ANDROID-102 is solved in https://github.com/ened/spring-android

Comment: How do I get that fix in my project? I have downloaded the snapshot from November 26th, but it's still not in it...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This one bit me as well, running Jelly Bean 4.2. After researching, it seems that it's happening because of a combination of Keep-Alive being set **and** using the standard J2SE HTTP Client, which I believe is HttpURLConnection.

There are 2 solutions that I can confirm are correct.

1) Switch off Keep-Alive.
For me, the solution given in Sebastian's answer, **System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");** didn't work. I had to use

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Connection", "Close");
```

and send those headers in an HttpEntity in the RestTemplate.
As mentioned, this solution could have an impact on performance

2) Change the HTTP Client.
In Spring for Android (tested on 1.0.1.RELEASE, but could be in earlier releases too) the default HTTP Client for a RestTemplate instance is determined by the version of Android on the device. API 9 or newer uses HttpURLConnection, older uses HTTPClient. To explicitly set the client to the old one, use

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

More info can be found here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e34
I'm not sure what impact this will have on performance, but I guess it's more performant than an app that doesn't work.

Anyway, hope that helps someone. I just wasted a week wild-goose-chasing this one down.

Comment: Looks like very good research. Thanks for your detailed information. Any idea why the keepAlive=false didn't work out for you? Probably it was changed in 4.2 again I guess.

Comment: No worries. I jump at any chance I can get to give back to this life-saving community.   
I'm not sure why setting keepAlive=false didn't work. It didn't produce an error, but it didn't change the headers in the inspected packets.   
I'd been banging my head against the wall for so long on the overarching issue that I saw no gain in trying to work out what was going wrong in this part.

Comment: Thank you... We have been getting ECONNRESET errors randomly... things work and then they stop working...I added my code below to set the interceptor for the RestTemplate to change the headers.  In confirmed on the server side that the Keep-Alive property was in the Header even though I tried using the System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false").. which also DID NOT work.  Only this option one seemed to work.

Comment: The same or similar error happend to me when I was using RoboSpice with AndroidSpring backend with HTTP GET requests with request JSON body. The second solution fixed it (the first does not)! Thank you for saving my life.

Answer (score 11):

http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/issues/detail?id=116 contains  a workaround in the latest comment:

> This is defenetly somehow connected with keepAlive connections.
>
> When I use:  **System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");** problems
>   disappears.
>
> But from my understanding keep alive connections are greatly increase
>   performance so it is better not to disable them.
>
> Im also awere that keep alive should be disabled for old versions, but
>   my device is Jelly Bean.

Once applied the error disappeared.
Seems it's not entirely related to Spring, but a JB problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced this issue and will able to resolved this issue after setting headers with following piece of code :

```
headers.set("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setOutputStreaming(false);

restTemplate.postForObject......
```