# Android annotations REST set header

Tags: android, http-headers, android-annotations

I'm using Android annotations, and recently discovered a bug [Spring Rest Template usage causes EOFException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182519/spring-rest-template-usage-causes-eofexception) which I don't know how to fix using annotations. I have post request:

```
@Post("base/setItem.php")
Item setItem(Protocol protocol);
```

Now, how do I set header

```
headers.set("Connection", "Close");
```

to this request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two solutions :

**Solution 1**

since AA 3.0 (still in snapshot), you can use [interceptors](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API#rest) field on `@Rest` annotation and implement a custom `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` which will set headers to each request :

```
public class HeadersRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        request.getHeaders().set("Connection", "Close");
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

With AA <= 2.7.1, you should create an `@EBean` annotated class with your Rest interface injected. Replace all injected Rest interface on other classes by this bean. In this new bean, create an `@AfterInject` method which will retrieve the `RestTemplate` instance and configure the interceptor of solution 1 :

*RestClient.java :*

```
@Rest(...)
public interface RestClient {
    @Post("base/setItem.php")
    Item setItem(Protocol protocol);

    RestTemplate getRestTemplate();
}
```

*RestClientProxy.java :*

```
@EBean
public class RestClientProxy {
    @RestService
    RestClient restClient;

    @AfterInject
    void init() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restClient.getRestTemplate();
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        interceptors.add(new HeadersRequestInterceptor());
    }
}
```