# How exactly should I add header to HTTP Get request with AndroidAnnotations?

Tags: android, http-get, android-annotations

I am using approach, described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366917/android-annotations-rest-set-header) to add my specific header to `HTTP` get request. But I can't understand how I need to change my code to make interceptor to do his job. Currently I am using something like this:

```
@RestService
ImwizardClient imwizardClient;

//some code

return  imwizardClient.getAllCategories();
```

where **getAllCategories()** is method, which makes get request. The request works correctly, but it doesn't add my custom header. So what do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Interceptor defined for your RestService class as documented [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API#interceptors)?

```
@Rest(interceptors = { HttpBasicAuthenticatorInterceptor.class })
public interface ImwizardClient {
 // ... snipped
}
```

Alternatively, the workaround posted in [this thread](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/323) seems to work reliably. Just define a custom MessageConverter for your RestService class.

```
public class GsonWithHeadersConverter extends GsonHttpMessageConverter {

@Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        setHeaders(outputMessage); //My method to put the additional headers :)
        super.writeInternal(o, outputMessage);
    }
```

}