# Im getting ERROR: null W/System.err(20560): java.io.EOFException from a network.request in Corona

Tags: networking, lua, coronasdk

```
    local body = "userId=31"
    local params = {}
    params.body = body

network.request( server/someifle.php", "POST", networkListenerRequests, params))
```

everything work fine, but at some random moments, I get an error in the networkListenerRequests.

If you read this post on stack overflow, [Spring Rest Template usage causes EOFException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182519/spring-rest-template-usage-causes-eofexception)
they mention something about an attribute keep alive. Can this be set in corona or does anyone know anything else I can do?

The error message:
E/Corona  (20560): ERROR: null
W/System.err(20560): java.io.EOFException
W/System.err(20560):    at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
W/System.err(20560):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:579)
W/System.err(20560):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
W/System.err(20560):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
W/System.err(20560):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
W/System.err(20560):    at network.NetworkRequest$AsyncNetworkRequestRunnable.run(NetworkRequest.java:1394)
W/System.err(20560):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Answer (score 1):

you can change any header of HTTP request with params.headers
In your case it will look like this

```
local body = "userId=31"
local params = {}
params.body = body
params.headers = {};

params.headers["Connection"] = "close";

network.request("server/someifle.php", "POST", networkListenerRequests, params))
```

Hope this helps