# I/O error for @Post request Android Annotations

Tags: android, android-annotations

I am doing a Post request to the API for my app, when I do this on a Nexus 5 everything goes fine but when I do this request on a HTC One X or an Samsung Galaxy S3 I get the following error:

```
07-01 11:48:36.605  30101-30251/eu.package.name E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-3
    org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: null; nested exception is java.io.EOFException
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:491)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:415)
            at eu.package.name.Rest.RESTClient_.signinFacebook(RESTClient_.java:155)
            at eu.package.name.Models.User.userLoginFacebook(User.java:91)
            at eu.package.name.Models.User_.access$101(User_.java:14)
            at eu.package.name.Models.User_$2.execute(User_.java:65)
            at org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:393)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.io.EOFException
            at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:579)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
            at com.splunk.mint.network.http.MonitorableHttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(MonitorableHttpURLConnection.java:362)
            at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:54)
            at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:80)
            at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:477)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:415)
            at eu.package.name.Rest.RESTClient_.signinFacebook(RESTClient_.java:155)
            at eu.package.name.Models.User.userLoginFacebook(User.java:91)
            at eu.package.name.Models.User_.access$101(User_.java:14)
            at eu.package.name.Models.User_$2.execute(User_.java:65)
            at org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:393)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The request I am doing is:

```
@Post("/signin/facebook")
LoginResponse signinFacebook(FacebookLoginRequest facebookLoginRequest);
```

I already tried to disable the keep-alive by doing the following:

```
restClient.setHeader("Connection", "Close");
LoginResponse loginResponse = restClient.signinFacebook(facebookLoginRequest);
```

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182519/spring-rest-template-usage-causes-eofexception) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to try out the okhttp client:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "url", requestFactory = OkHttpClientHttpRequestFactory.class)
```

This should solve lots of problems related to the standard Android http client, including this one. Please note the `OkHttpClientHttpRequestFactory` is only available in Spring Android 2.0.

**EDIT:** You have to declare the following dependencies to use `OkHttpClientHttpRequestFactory`:

```
compile "org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M2"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0"
```

Comment: I get the message from Android Studio: "Cannot resolve symbol 'OkHttpClientHttpRequestFactory'"

Comment: As I said, you have to use Spring for Android 2.0.

Comment: I am using Spring for Android 2.0 but I am now using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory instead of  OkHttpClientHttpRequestFactory and it works good now! Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer a bit with dependency information

Comment: Ah, I didn't had the last one. Thanks.